# macOS keeps restarting due to apparent kernel/CPU panic

Tags: big-sur, crash, kernel-panic, kernel, kernel-extensions

My Macbook Air 13" 2019 running Big Sur 11.4 has been having these issues for a while.
I've narrowed down the issue to a third party kext as running in safe mode prevents restarting/CPU panic. Below is the most recent report. How should I fix this?

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff029b26024): macOS watchdog detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 20G224
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xc1
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70707060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x1614
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000021a98000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff028a9c000
mach_absolute_time: 0x4506dac0f
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x620da156 0x00095ba2
  Sleep   : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Wake    : 0x00000000 0x00000000
  Calendar: 0x620da455 0x000c3278

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff06e1bc000 - 0xfffffff06e1cc000
Native    : 0xffffffe0000d8000 - 0xffffffe6000d8000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb007e8000 - 0xffffffeb049a4000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb01fe8000 - 0xffffffeb02248000
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff0299e955c, LR=0xfffffff0299e955c, FP=0xffffffeb0ea4bdc0
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f2968658: 0 pages, 202 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f3012798, backtrace: 0xffffffeb0ebbb670, tid: 391
          lr: 0xfffffff029283388  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbb6b0
          lr: 0xfffffff029283118  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbb720
          lr: 0xfffffff0293bbeac  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbb7a0
          lr: 0xfffffff0293bb03c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbb850
          lr: 0xfffffff0298e55fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbb860
          lr: 0xfffffff029282e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbbf0
          lr: 0xfffffff029282e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbc50
          lr: 0xfffffff02a3d7488  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbc70
          lr: 0xfffffff029b26024  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbca0
          lr: 0xfffffff029b12f5c  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbd00
          lr: 0xfffffff029b19410  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbd50
          lr: 0xfffffff029b14e48  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbdf0
          lr: 0xfffffff029b12640  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbe70
          lr: 0xfffffff0299c4db4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbea0
          lr: 0xfffffff02982b3a4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbee0
          lr: 0xfffffff02982abb4  fp: 0xffffffeb0ebbbf20
          lr: 0xfffffff0298f05a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Edit: since I posted this question a second crash/panic occurred. Here is the log.

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff024619740): "void AppleEmbeddedPCIeUpLinkMgmt::_linkInterruptAction(IOInterruptEventSource *, int): " "A link timeout has been seen after 650000 microseconds and 49999 iterations." @AppleEmbeddedPCIeUpLinkMgmt.cpp:3979
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 20G224
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0xd
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0xec
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x405060400
PCIeUp link state: 0x89271611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x000000001c578000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff02357c000
mach_absolute_time: 0xb1a005a8
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x620db4aa 0x000f3c8c
  Sleep   : 0x620db5a9 0x00068a3f
  Wake    : 0x620db5aa 0x0007e663
  Calendar: 0x620db601 0x00074bc5

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff0901bc000 - 0xfffffff0901cc000
Native    : 0xffffffe00004c000 - 0xffffffe60004c000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb0075c000 - 0xffffffeb049a0000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb01f5c000 - 0xffffffeb021dc000
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff02430b3a4, LR=0xfffffff02430b3a4, FP=0xffffffeb0f473ee0
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f2974658: 0 pages, 203 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f2e4b3c8, backtrace: 0xffffffeb0eb2b780, tid: 256
          lr: 0xfffffff023d63388  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2b7c0
          lr: 0xfffffff023d63118  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2b830
          lr: 0xfffffff023e9beac  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2b8b0
          lr: 0xfffffff023e9b03c  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2b960
          lr: 0xfffffff0243c55fc  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2b970
          lr: 0xfffffff023d62e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bd00
          lr: 0xfffffff023d62e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bd60
          lr: 0xfffffff024eb742c  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bd80
          lr: 0xfffffff024619740  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bdc0
          lr: 0xfffffff024613d4c  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2be50
          lr: 0xfffffff02430c9dc  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bea0
          lr: 0xfffffff02430b3a4  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bee0
          lr: 0xfffffff02430abb4  fp: 0xffffffeb0eb2bf20
          lr: 0xfffffff0243d05a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: If you've narrowed the issue down, then remove the kext.

Comment: I don't know what the kext is, that's my issue.